# How do you release an MPMoviePlayerViewController after playback finishes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am using an MPMoviePlayerViewController to play a video in iOS. When the video stops or crashes, I would like to close this view controller and release it. To simulate the crash, I've passed in a nonexistent file path:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* p = [
    [MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init
];
self.player = p;
[p release];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:self.player.moviePlayer
];
self.player.moviePlayer.contentURL = @"purposelyFake.mp4";
```

This will immediately trigger the following callback.

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish
{
    if (self.player != nil) {
        [self.player.moviePlayer stop];
        self.player = nil
    }
}
```

`self.player` is a nonatomic retained property, so setting it to `nil` should release it. This clears the memory, but my log shows this warning:

> An instance 0x127b20 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key
>   value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was
>   leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object.
>   Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.

The reason is because `moviePlayBackDidFinish` is called twice when the video crashes. Once to say `MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded` and again to say `MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError`. The `MPMoviePlayerViewController` becomes deallocated while the second notification is still being sent. My question is: how do I get rid of this warning? Keep in mind that in normal playback finishing, only `MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded` is issued, so I can't just hardcode it to only release whenever I receive two notifications in a row.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback method try removing yourself as an observer of the notification before you release it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object: myMPMoviePlayerController];
```

Comment: Tried that and I still get the same warning.